# How to fix an "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" error?

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to make a **TicTacToe** game. I'm trying to use this `checkForWinner` function but keep getting errors. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet weak var CurrentLetterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label6: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label7: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label8: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label9: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label10: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label11: UILabel!
    let letter = "XOXOXOXOXO"
    var moveCounter = 0
    var currentLetter:Character!
    var labelArray = [UILabel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        labelArray.append(label1)
        labelArray.append(label2)
        labelArray.append(label3)
        labelArray.append(label4)
        labelArray.append(label5)
        labelArray.append(label6)
        labelArray.append(label7)
        labelArray.append(label8)
        labelArray.append(label9)
        labelArray.append(label10)
        labelArray.append(label11)

        getCharacter()

    }
    func getCharacter(){
        let myRange = Range<String.Index>(start: letter.startIndex.advancedBy(moveCounter), end: letter.startIndex.advancedBy(moveCounter + 1))
        CurrentLetterLabel.text = letter.substringWithRange(myRange)
        currentLetter = Character(letter.substringWithRange(myRange))
    }

    func clearLabels(Action:UIAlertAction){
        label1.text = ""
        label2.text = ""
        label3.text = ""
        label4.text = ""
        label5.text = ""
        label6.text = ""
        label7.text = ""
        label9.text = ""
        label10.text = ""
        label11.text = ""
    }
    func presentWinningAlert(){
        moveCounter = 0
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "byr", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: clearLabels)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)        
    }

    @IBAction func onTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Here")
        let selectedPoint = sender.locationInView(self.view)
        print(selectedPoint)
        for label in labelArray{
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label1.frame, selectedPoint){
                label1.text = String(currentLetter)

            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label2.frame, selectedPoint){
                label2.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label3.frame, selectedPoint){
                label3.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label4.frame, selectedPoint){
                label4.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label5.frame, selectedPoint){
                label5.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label6.frame, selectedPoint){
                label6.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label7.frame, selectedPoint){
                label7.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label8.frame, selectedPoint){
                label8.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label9.frame, selectedPoint){
                label9.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
            if CGRectContainsPoint(label10.frame, selectedPoint){
                label10.text = String(currentLetter)
            }
        }

        moveCounter++

            if moveCounter == 9{
                presentWinningAlert()
            }
            getCharacter()
    }

    func checkForWinner(){
        if label1.text == label2.text && label2.text == label3.text && label3.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label3.text!)")
        }

        else if label4.text == label5.text && label5.text == label6.text && label6.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label6.text!)")   
        }
        else if label7.text == label8.text && label8.text == label9.text && label9.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label9.text!)")
        }    
        else if label1.text == label4.text && label4.text == label7.text && label7.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label7.text!)")
        }
        else if label2.text == label5.text && label5.text == label8.text && label8.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label8.text!)")
        }
        else if label3.text == label6.text && label6.text == label9.text && label9.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label9.text!)")
        }
        else if label1.text == label5.text && label5.text == label9.text && label9.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label9.text!)")
        }
        else if label3.text == label5.text && label5.text == label7.text && label7.text != "" {
            presentWinningAlert("\(label7.text!)")
        }

        if moveCounter == 9            
        {
            presentWinningAlert("No One")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the precise error message, and *where* does it occur? I cannot see  that checkForWinner is called anywhere. – And please try to reduce the code to the relevant part: Not all your code, but a *minimal* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: It occurs when attempting to "presenWinningAlert("\(label8.text!")

Comment: So your problem is presentWinningAlert, not checkForWinner. – Well, your presentWinningAlert method has no parameters, but you are calling it with one argument. The compiler is right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the function with a string parameter, but the function does not take the string parameter. 
Either the call should be

```
presentWinningAlert()
```

without passing any arguments or the function should be modified to

```
func presentWinningAlert(title: String){
moveCounter = 0
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "byr", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler's message is misleading, and other languages would give a better message instead, something like:

```c
Parameter type mismatch. Can not implicitly convert X to Y.
```

How to reproduce:

```swift
let myVariable: Int32 = 100;
let size = CGSize(width: myVariable, height: myVariable);
```

How to fix:

```swift
let myVariable: Int32 = 100;
let size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(myVariable), height: CGFloat(myVariable));
```