# error : Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

var arrs = [String]()
func addVars(fn: @autoclosure () -> ()) {
    arrs = Array(repeating: "", count: 3)
    fn()
    print(arrs[1])
    }
addVars(fn: arrs.insert("Nice to meet you.",at:1))
```

The above code works well. If I replace the code as the fowlloing:

```
var arrs = [String]()
func addVars(fn: @autoclosure () -> ()) {
arrs = Array(repeating: "", count: 3)

print(fn())
}

addVars(fn: arrs.count)
```

I do get this error: Argument passed to call that takes no arguments at addVars(fn: arrs.count)

Comment: I'm trying to know why addVars(fn: arrs.insert("Nice to meet you.",at:1)) is possible to use and why addVars(fn: arrs.count) isn't possible to use. the code. I was reading a book about @autoclosure and was curious why one is possible and the other isn't.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35301738

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix an "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301738/how-to-fix-an-argument-passed-to-call-that-takes-no-arguments-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func addVars(fn: @autoclosure () -> ())
```

In this function, you are passing a function as a parameter. `arrs.count` is Integer so it will give an error, whereas `arrs.insert("Nice to meet you.",at:1)` is of type `()` so it will execute.

**UPDATE**: ***How do I know if something is of type () or no?***

If a function does not return something, its return type is `Void` i.e, `()` .

```
arrs.remove(at: 0) // this return an array by removing the value at 0 position. Hence, its return type is [String] not Void
```

whereas,

```
arrs.insert("Nice to meet you.",at:1) // this just adds value and returns nothing, hence Void.
```

> In Xcode, when you call a function, Xcode shows you the return type of
>   the function too. See the image below. You can use it to know the
>   return type.

[image]

Also, refer to this article to learn more about [Functions and their return types.](https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/function-in-swift-39510bc421d5)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask you in more detail about this? How do I know if something is of type () or no? I mean, I looked them. insert is a method and count is a property. a method is of type ()? and property can't be of type ()? I replaced the code with addVars(fn:arrs.remove(at: 0)). remove is a method, but I still get the same error. maybe this is not a correct way to tell which one is type of ()?

Comment: @lulzo updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. I got the gist of it!